# AnonymousUser problem in Django, Feedback App

Tags: python, django, authentication, feedback

```
user    = models.ForeignKey(User,)
```

I have a user foreignkey in models.py

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    feedback.user = request.user
else:
    feedback.user = 'something'
```

In views.py, If user logged in feedback.user area, write username else write something there.
How can I do this in Django.

I was trying to django-feedback and it was like just

```
feedback.user = request.user
```

Like this, it was giving the error below.

```
Cannot assign "<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser 
object at 0x2dbcf50>": "Feedback.user" must be a "User" instance
```

I am working on localhost. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Either [require the user to be logged in for the view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required), or handle it yourself and assign None.